# State management in a generic flutter app that is built at runtime

Tags: flutter, state-management

first of all: I'm new to stackoverflow and to Flutter/declarative frameworks, so if I just missed searching for the right tags, please excuse me.

**Short**

How can I acheive a decent state management for a fully generic app which is built out of basic widgets from scratch on runtime? As the interaction is completety generic as well, potentially all states of all elements can be changed from many sources.

**Long**

We are currently working on a mobile client for our application management system and chose Flutter/Dart as we won't need to have two completely different apps for iOS and Android but now we encounter some difficulties implementing our imperative code from former client apps (written in AS, Objective-C, Java) in Flutter.

The most important point in our system is that the whole app structure is saved in a database which is downloaded at runtime and then parsed to a tree-like data structure with parent-child-relations. This data structure is used to build the UI with our basic custom widgets (label, image, group, ...). So the whole app is completely generic. The interaction with the app is generic as well, generally allowing the state of every widget to change at any time. The state of an element can be changed by multiple sources (by interactions which are handled globally, implicitely by the parent or by any ohter element with a state link to synchronize states).

E.g. an interaction can be defined that increases the page of a gallery. The gallery itself is a group element with three child elements: an image, a label and a rectangle as background. On changing of the group's page it informs it's children that the page changed and they in return check all their settings (size, position, file, textetc.) if they need to be updated. In this case the file setting of the image and the text setting of the label would be updated so the two widgets representing these two elements would need to be redrawn, the background of course wouldn't. Anyhow keep in mind that this gallery and the interaction are generic and I have no access to them before the data strucutre has been built on runtime. The gallery could as well consist of an additional label as well or the interaction could change the state of another group which is the parent of the gallery.

**Current solution**

Kinda hacky, I made setState() of the WidgetStates available to the element's data structure object. This works for now but I feel not comfortable with working against the declarative nature of the framework and I am sure this will produce bugs sooner or later.

**Research**

I've read some articles on state management solutions with `scoped_model`, `BloC` and `Redux` but it appears they all work with some kind of stream/subscription which seems not really practicable as we would need multiple streams for every single widget. There is no global state, every element has it's own state, but this state must potentially be accessible from everywere.

**Help**

I would be glad if someone could show me an example where something like a complete access to the state of every element is implemented without the hacky approach of making setState() available to a data structure object. And of course any ideas, hints or corrections to my assumptions are appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You put a lot of effort on that port, that's cool! Sadly StackOverflow isn't really the right place for such question. It qualifies as both "too broad" and "option based".

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "option based"? Just for me to avoid doing the same mistake again.

Comment: I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. It contains a definition of what this means

Comment: Ok got it. You meant "opinion based" :)

Comment: Oh indeed, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You might want to wrap your head around the `BloC` concept which is used in Dart/Flutter and is AFAIK also recommended by google.

Thats the concept where you separate your business logic from your UI code.
Most tutorials show how to properly integrate some sort of web API with BloCs but in your case you'd instead prefer hooking into a database source.   Which should be totally fine!

I would recommend **Felix Angelov's** excellent library called [flutter_bloc](https://github.com/felangel/bloc) and introduction/tutorial to `BloCs` in Flutter. He does a great job explaining the system by walking you through a couple of different examples.

You can find the guide here: https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/gettingstarted

Comment: BLoC is not the only recommended solution by Flutter though. `scoped_model` is too.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I've already had a look at BloC and had the feeling it would not fit a generic application with it's Stream logic but guess I will nevertheless try to somehow implement a BloC-like logic with a decent scaling for potentially infinitely large apps.